# Calculating number of black pixels per row and column of an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to openCV and Python.I want to calculate total number of black pixels per row and per column of an image.Can anyone give a hint or some help?

Comment: Hint: use "reduce"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Miki suggests, you can take advantage of `cv2.reduce`.

1. Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create a mask containing `1` where a black pixel was, and `0` for any other intensity.
2. Now call [`cv2.reduce`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) twice (once per axis), performing a `REDUCE_SUM`, and setting the output data type to be a 32 bit integer.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Make random image
img = np.zeros((128,128),np.uint8)
cv2.randu(img, 0, 256)

mask = np.uint8(np.where(img == 0, 1, 0))

col_counts = cv2.reduce(mask, 0, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)
row_counts = cv2.reduce(mask, 1, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32SC1)

print "Column counts: ", col_counts.flatten().tolist()
print "Row counts: ", row_counts.flatten().tolist()
```

Sample output:

```
Column counts:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
Row counts:  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) you can find `countNonZero` function that counts non-zero elements in an array, in your case it will be a row or a column.

```
cv2.countNonZero(src) → retval
```

PS: That function will return the number of non black pixels, all you've to do is subtract that number from the number of pixels (resolution or row*cols).